# How to run same task in parallel on multiple hosts with different parameters using fabric?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parameters, parallel-processing, fabric

I am new to fabric and I intended to run a task with different hosts(maybe) and different parameters. And I set host list

```
env.hosts = ['host1', 'host1', 'host2', 'host3']
env.passwords = {
    'host1:22': 'password1',
    'host1:22': 'password1',
    'host2:22': 'password2',
    'host3:22': 'password3'
}
```

I run the task in parallel with same parameter and got only three output, maybe there are same host and password configured in `env`. Actually each parameter assigned to the task differs, but I can only assign the same argument by entering `fab function:parameter` in shell.
So can I configure parameters the same way like env.hosts or env.passwords, maybe something like this?

```
env.parameters = ['para1', 'para2', 'para3', 'para4']
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `set()` of your list is made of only 3 distinct hosts. So you'll only have 3 runs of your command. Fabric dedupes host lists automatically.

If you'd like to change this, you'll likely need to start using the `execute()` function. [Here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.11/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute) is the section in the docs about this function.

An example of how you'd want to use it would be like this

```
env.hosts = ['host1', 'host1', 'host2', 'host3']
env.passwords = {
    'host1:22': 'password1',
    'host1:22': 'password1',
    'host2:22': 'password2',
    'host3:22': 'password3'
}
env.parameters = ['para1', 'para2', 'para3', 'para4']  

def bar(arg):
    #do some work with arg

def foo():
    for index, host in enumerate(env.hosts):
        execute(bar, env.parameters[index] hosts=host)
```

Comment: This makes `bar` executed in serial using `for` loop, but I intended to run same task with different parameters in parallel using `@parallel` decorator. Is there any way to make it possible? @Morgan